# WordPress Genesis Framework: <!--nextpage--> not working

Tags: php, wordpress, genesis

I am using the genesis framework on nearly all of my wordpress sites.

I am running a blog with extremely large posts which I want to split into multiple pages. Added `<!--nextpage-->` in the editor but in the frontend WordPress outputs `<!-nextpage->` with two "-" missing.

So I assume that the "operator" `<!--nextpage-->` is not processed. So what can I do to make this work? I really like to have this feature in genesis!

Thanks a lot for every hint or idea!

Comment: Plugin conflict(s)?  Something appears to be mangling that comment, it should work.  Some poorly coded plugins can make a mess of your content.

Comment: @cale_b thx for your answer. problem solved - had to insert the snippet into the text editor mode. :D